# Sequelize v5 - Raw Queries return undefined when using QueryTypes.DELETE

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to delete a record in the database with the **DELETE** query type, Sequelize always returns the undefined value.

```sql
let userId = 1;

sequelize.query('DELETE FROM user where user_id = ?',
    {replacements: [userId],type: sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE})
    .then(result => {
        console.log('result ', result);
    });

// result undefined
```

Query type: **SELECT**, **UPDATE** still working properly

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried QueryTypes.BULKDELETE? I came across similar problem, and it worked. Anyway I am deleting multiple records

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried, and it worked in the sequelize version 6.31.1

```
result = await sequelize.query(
    "DELETE FROM Orders where UserId = :userId",
    {
        logging : console.log,
        replacements    :
        {
            userId     : "123"
        },
        raw     : true,
        type    : sequelize.QueryTypes.BULKDELETE
    }
);
console.log(result);
```

result would print how many records were effected (deleted) when executing the  SQL.